# Most efficient way to shift arrays

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to shift numerical 2D arrays along its dimensions as follows:

```
(A = Partition[Range[9], 3])//TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & 2. & 3. \\
 4. & 5. & 6. \\
 7. & 8. & 9. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
(AR = PadLeft[A, {3, 4}][[All, ;; -2]]) // TableForm
(AL = PadRight[A, {3, 4}][[All, 2 ;;]]) // TableForm
(AD = PadLeft[A, {4, 3}][[;; -2, All]]) // TableForm
(AU = PadRight[A, {4, 3}][[2 ;;, All]]) // TableForm
```

$$\begin{align}AL&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0. & 1. & 2. \\
 0. & 4. & 5. \\
 0. & 7. & 8. \\
\end{array}
\right),&
AR&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2. & 3. & 0. \\
 5. & 6. & 0. \\
 8. & 9. & 0. \\
\end{array}
\right),\\
AD&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0. & 0. & 0.\\
 1. & 2. & 3. \\
 4. & 5. & 6. \\
\end{array}
\right),&
AU&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4. & 5. & 6. \\
 7. & 8. & 9. \\
 0. & 0. & 0. \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{align}$$

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2546/9469) a question of array rotation has been asked. I am asking for the *efficient numerical shift*. Actually, I need to achieve even a simpler goal of computing the sum

```
(B = AL + AR + AU + AD) // TableForm
```

$$\begin{align}B&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6. & 9. & 8. \\
 13. & 20. & 17. \\
 12. & 21. & 14. \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}.$$

---

In real application, the dimensions are not $3\times3$ but $201\times201$, and this operation needs to be performed repeatedly.
As an answer, I am expecting some super efficient function `ArraySpread` defined as follows:

```
ArraySpread[a_?ArrayQ] := Module[{...},
  ....
  ]
```

such that

```
B=ArraySpread[A]
```

My current implementation:

```
ArraySpread[a_?ArrayQ] := Module[{al, ar, au, ad, dim},
  dim = Length[a];
  ar = PadLeft[a, {dim, dim + 1}][[All, ;; -2]];
  al = PadRight[a, {dim, dim + 1}][[All, 2 ;;]];
  ad = PadLeft[a, {dim + 1, dim}][[;; -2, All]];
  au = PadRight[a, {dim + 1, dim}][[2 ;;, All]];
  al + ar + ad + au
  ]
```

performs as

```
an = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {201, 201}]
RepeatedTiming[ArraySpread[an]]

(*0.036*)
```

But can one achieve a better performance?

Comment: Some of you outputs show `Real` arrays, but all the inputs seem to be `Integer` arrays.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good catch, in the process of typing I realized that for me only real case is of interest, but I overlooked that some results were obtained with the previous command. I will correct it now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`ArrayPad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html). It's not a lot faster, but doesn't need the dimension to be explicitly determined:

```
ArraySpread2[a_] := ArrayPad[a, {{1, -1}, 0}] 
                  + ArrayPad[a, {{-1, 1}, 0}] 
                  + ArrayPad[a, {0, {1, -1}}]
                  + ArrayPad[a, {0, {-1, 1}}]

an = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {201, 201}];
RepeatedTiming[ArraySpread[an];]
(* {0.023, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[ArraySpread2[an];]
(* {0.020, Null} *)
```

After some tinkering with the parameters, here is another approach using [`ListConvolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html) that is more than 10 times faster:

```
ArraySpread3[a_] := ListConvolve[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, a, {2, -2}, 0]

RepeatedTiming[ArraySpread3[an];]
(* {0.0017, Null} *)

ArraySpread[an] == ArraySpread2[an] == ArraySpread3[an]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Around 10% faster. Not bad!

Comment: @yarchik Now it's 10x faster :)

Comment: Amazing, really amazing! I should not have forgotten the FFT approach.